# How to find on what ranges one sorting algorithm is better than other?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I'm reading the book "Introduction to algorithms" and want to solve one task from it. But don't know the best way how to find solution.

The task is:

We have 2 sorting algorithms. Сomplexity of first one is $8 n^2$, the second is $64 n \lg n$. I want to find the range of $n$ when first algorithm is better than second.

I understand different ways how to solve it:

1. I can take numbers one by one from range $[2..n]$ an find both values. According to them find a place when values of first algorithm become greater than second.
2. I understand that I can solve $8 n ^2$ < $64 n \lg n$. But have no idea how to do it. Maybe someone can assist with it or give a link where to read.
3. I can build graphics and find intersection point. But I had a problem with it. I don't want to build them on the paper. I found such online programm as **Sage**. But I can't find how to build graphic for logarithm. I'm trying:

   a=plot(8*n^2)

   b=plot(64*n*log(10, n), rgbcolor='red')

   (a+b).show()

   But it's not working. Maybe somebody can help with it? And what is the most popular     programm for such mathematics tasks?

Comment: WolframAlpha is handy for one off things like this. Here is a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8+n%5E2+%3D+64+n+log%28n%29+for+n+%5Cge+1) including the intersection.

Comment: When I opened that page first time, I saw plot for natural logarithm, but I switched to base 10 logarithm and get correct number. I think it's `6.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the graphics, put:

```
8*x**2, 64*x*log x
```

in google. You will get the graph of the two functions and "see" the interval requested.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple 16:

```
solve(8*n^2<64*n*log[2](n));
```

$$\text {RealRange} \left( \text {Open} \left( -{\frac {8\; \text {LambertW}
 \left( -\frac{\ln  \left( 2 \right)}{8}  \right) }{\ln  \left( 2 \right) }
} \right) ,{\it Open} \left( -{\frac {8\;\text{ LambertW} \left( -1,-
\frac{\ln  \left( 2 \right)}{8}  \right) }{\ln  \left( 2 \right) }} \right) 
 \right) 
$$

```
evalf(%);
```

$$ \text{RealRange}(\text{Open}(1.099997030),\text{Open}(43.55926044))$$

So for integers $n$ the answer is $2 \le n \le 43$.

Comment: Intersection if this 2 graphics gave me the point `6.5`. So, my number is 6. Do you think your results correct?

Comment: Sorry, I had the impression it was supposed to be the base $2$ logarithm (which is commonly used when dealing with algorithms).  Apparently you want base $10$, in which case the intersection is indeed at approximately $6.5$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.